# What does a TPM error message when booting mean?

Tags: bios, tpm

I have a Gateway MT6728 laptop I was given to have, if I could fix it.

When the computer boots, it displays the message: `No TPM or TPM has problem`. Allegedly, this problem occurred after browsing to a video on YouTube.  Regardless, the OS will not boot and the BIOS seemingly fails to boot as well.

Does anyone know what this means, and how to fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Edit as I missed the will not boot part-

I think this is a bog standard Windows will not load error. If you have Vista or 7, try inserting the CD, going to repair and doing a startup repair.

If this is XP, go to recovery console and type the following

```
chkdsk /R
fixboot
```

If these methods do not work, start a new question asking for specific help of repairing Windows, however it may be quicker just to reinstall.

Regarding TPM-

I get this on my laptop as well.

It is nothing to worry about, it simply means your laptop's BIOS supports [TPM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trusted_Platform_Module) and your laptop does not have one.

It has either always been there and gone un-noticed, or the BIOS was recently updated to a version that supports [TPM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trusted_Platform_Module) and it is alerting you now that it knows it doesn't have one.

[TPM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trusted_Platform_Module) is used for encryption amongst other activities, if you do not know what it is, the chances are you do not need it.

Comment: If there's nothing wrong why can't he boot?

Comment: @CalIF, he said "Bios seemingly fails to book", I missed that, however, I think he has **always** had this TPM message and ignored it but now that there is another standard error - Windows not booting, he is attributing it to that problem

Answer (score 1):

Go into BIOS and disable or reset the TPM. If you can't get into BIOS, first Clear the CMOS using the jumper or button on the motherboard.

That should work, if it doesn't, then you are in trouble. You need to get the board to boot into BIOS before you can do anything like reinstall the OS. Make sure you board is stripped down to the bare essentials to allow it to boot.